# Multiple embedded AND in the Where part of a Select in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, syntax

I use PostgreSQL 10 and I have the following table.

```
id  name   place
1    20     56
2    21     51
3    21     53
4    21     54
```

the `select` I want to do is something like

`select id from mytable where place = 51 and place=53 and place=54 and name = 21`

I have to end up with id `2 3 4` but I can only use `place` and `name` .

I also tried `select id from mytable where (place = 51 and name = 21) and (place=53 and name = 21) and (place=54 and name = 21)`

but I keep getting an empty set of results.

How can I syntax that?

Thank you

Comment: Use: place in(51,53,54) and name = 21. A column can be equal at the same time (note you’re using AND) to more than 1 value.

Comment: @sagi Thank, it worked right away. Fell free to turn this into a normal answer, so I can upvote and choose as the right one

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT id
FROM my_table 
WHERE place IN (51,53,54) AND name = 21
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you get empty results is because you have no records where place equals both 51 **and** 53. Obviously place can only be one value per record.

I assume you are trying to return any results that match any of your criteria? For that try this:

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE place IN (51, 53, 54) OR name IN (21);
```

If you want to exclude any results where name is not 21 then use AND instead.

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE place IN (51, 53, 54) AND name = 21;
```

OR means return records if it matches either 'condition a' **or** 'condition b'.
AND means return record only if it matchs 'condition a' **AND** (as well as) 'condition b'

IN means return record if it matches any of the values **IN** the list.